# "Soft link" element in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web

Suppose that there is a given HTML subtree which is repeated across multiple points in my code:

```
<div class='content'>
    ...
    <p>This is repeated many times</p>
    ....
    <p>This is repeated many times</p>
    ...
    <p>This is repeated many times</p>
</div>
```

Is there a way to create a kind of "soft link" for the first `<p>` so that each repetition could just point to it? Or there is a better alternative for this kind of problem?

## Update

It seems that my question is unclear, So I will try to clarify it by giving an example of a imaginary solution. Suppose that HTML provides an `<alias>`, which acts like a pointer to another element. So, instead of repeating the same element over and over, I could do something like that:

```
<div class='content'>
    ...
    <p id='repeat'>This is repeated many times</p>
    ....
    <alias from='repeat'/>
    ...
    <alias from='repeat'/>
</div>
```

And the HTML would be rendered in the same way.

Comment: Are you talking reusing the same markup in different parts of your document, or about an anchor that scrolls the page to a specific point?

Comment: I have, but this is something that I see now and then in many sites. I am wondering if with an alias, it would not be easier to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: It's still unclear what you're asking, could you add more details? Does any of the two current answers answer your question?

Comment: @bfavaretto I updated my question with an exemaple of what I mean. Hope it helps!

Comment: Okay. Sounds like something better fit for the server-side. It's possible with JavaScript, but not ideal (bad for SEO, for example). What kind of server-side technology you're using?

Comment: @bfvaretto we use PHP, Joomla and Symfony2.

Comment: So I'd just have the HTML snipped in a PHP variable, and `echo` it whenever necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as @Cerbrus and @bfavaretto have commented, the answer unfortunally is no, there is no way to use something such as an `<alias>` without resorting to JavaScript. Since search engines ignore JavaScript, they would ignore part of the page, and that would really be bad for the site as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class='content'>
    ...
    <p id='firstP'>This is repeated many times</p>
    ...
    <p>This is repeated many times</p>
    ...
    <p>This is repeated many times</p>
</div>
<a href='#firstP'>Link to the first &lt;p&gt; tag.</a>
```

**[Example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/H32Wz/1/)**

Comment: Unfortunally, my question was unclear about what I wanted. The problem is not to provide a link to the first repetition, but to create an alias so that each elemente would reference the first one. So, for example if JavaScript changed the inner HTML of the original element, each repetition would reflect that change.

Comment: @Metalcoder: Ah, right. I'm afraid that's not possible. HTML has no templating engine.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood the question.
same as others : cant do this in HTML.
because HTML havnt alias tag!
but i think it could be doing with linking "js" and "html events".
you must write a bridge.
for example: set id for your tagS. and set "change like event" for your alias tag!
and write a bridge js function to your ID.